# using a named function in an anonymous function

Tags: jquery

I am have made some functions to to take the user down to the section once it has been clicked on. I want to be good and stick to the DRY principles and not repeat myself!

When the menu is clicked I want the burger menu I have made to be closed but I don't want to keep putting the this one line of code into ever function I have made.

So how do I feed my name named function into my anonymous functions

So i want to feed this ....
    $(function(menuCLose){
       $('.burger-menu').removeClass('open');
    });

into these....

```
$('.sub-header ul #about-me, .burger-menu ul #about-me').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.about-me').offset().top  
}, 900);
                });

$('.sub-header ul #personal-training, .burger-menu ul #personal-training').click(                function() {

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.personal-training').offset().top 
    }, 900)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think this does

```
$(function(menuCLose){ $('.burger-menu').removeClass('open'); });
```

But this actually aliases `$` to `menuCLose` So you could use `menuCLose` as a selector. It does not create a function named menuCLose that you can call as an event. Now you can call `menuCLose('...jquery functions` like below:

```
 menuCLose('.burger-menu').removeClass('open');
```

Use the conventional method instead:

```
function menuClose(){
    $('.burger-menu').removeClass('open');
}

.....click(function(){
    menuClose();
});
```

Keep it simple.